# How to display information related to the clicked item using javascript in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, listbox

I have information for all the items in ListBox stored at server side in some datastructure. On client click I want to display information related to the clicked item  without postback.
I want to handle this from client side using javascript.
As I'm new to javascript, please tell me how should I do this. 
If lets say there are 100 items in ListBox, So I have a dictionary of 100 items in C# Code.dictionary key is item and value at this key is the information, which I want to display to the User.
so I can I use this dictionry at javascript code.

Comment: Post your html markup.

Answer (score 0):

Here is, in short, how I would do this:

1. Create a service that returns a json representation, e g using WebAPI:

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       private Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string> 
       { 
           {"a", "aaaaaa"}, 
           {"b", "bbbbb"}, 
           {"c", "ccccccc"}
       };

       public Dictionary<string, string> Get()
       {
           return values;
       }
   }
   ```
2. When the page is loaded use Javascript and jQuery to consume the service through an ajax-call.
3. Use jQuery to hook up the .change-event for the list box, so when the selection change you can pick the information to display from the list you fetched from the service.

   ```
   $(function() {
       // 2.
       $.getJSON("/api/Values", function (data) {
           // Store data in listbox 
       }

       // 3.
       $("#listbox").change(function () {
           // Display information
       });
   }
   ```